# Extracting Information using Regx

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle

I'm trying to extract few key words, specially from the attached data sample. I was wondering if i can use Oracle Regex or some advance natural language functions (if there are any)?

From the attached sample. I need to extract the individual associations with the previous entities from "notes" column . Following is the output I need from the attached sample . I have around 6K notes like this.

```
 id Notes
 1  Mr. Stewart Little is a Co-Founder and serves as the Chief Information Officer at Rinco. He is the faculyt of Department of Computer Science at Kinteic Enginerring Universtity. He was the Director at Mercury Marine.
 2  Ms. Lindsy Grahm is a Co-Founder and serves as a Head of Design at Mercedes. Lindsy is a Forbes 30 Under 30 recipient, and most recently was a Co-Founder of Thrivent, an enterprise datacenter management platform started from a Harvard University research project.
 3  Mr. Michael Johnson is a Co-Founder and Board Member of RedTraffic, where he serves as Chief Executive Officer. He is a Co-Founder of Majesic Solutions. Prior to this, he co-founded Pride Systems. He also co-founded and was a Board Member of Excel Capital. He also served as Chief Operating Officer at the New York Times Publishing Corporation.
 4  Mr. Shawn Reiding is a Co-Founder and serves as the Chief Executive Officer at Captial Corp. He was also the Co-Founder and CTO at Rinco.
 5  Ms. Sheena Jackson is a Co-Founder and serves as the Chief Executive Officer at MightyTalk. Previously, she served as a Director, Product Management at Aero Network.
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

```
id Previous_Associations 
1  Mercury Marine
2  Thrivent
3  Pride System, Excel Capital
4  Rinco
5  Aero Network
```

Comment: Create another table with the set of firms and their hierarchy. Then simply match and evaluate it to the  association with the highest hierarchy.

Comment: It is not possible with regex without a pattern. Do you know any pattern for example word after "at" ?

Comment: @Fact perhaps we can start with the pattern starting before word like “previously” or “recently” or “prior”. Can we use that ??

Comment: You can do that but again , how many words before those patterns.. and also do can you expect to loose data because some of the notes do not fall in your criteria. If you want fussy match and dont care about missing out , you may use regular expression